# Django DRF More Detail After Fetching Object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

New to DRF (and REST in general).

Models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Result(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='results')
    person = models.CharField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Serializers:

```
class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model = Result

class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model = Event
```

Viewsets:

```
class ResultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Result.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResultSerializer

class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

Router:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'events', EventViewSet)
```

URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This works fine, I can go to http://mysite/api and see "events" with a link to http://mysite/api/events/. From there each event has a link to http://mysite/api/events/id. So far so good.

If I change the event serializer to this, it will also include all the results (for that event) from Result:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    results = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
            model = Event
```

This also works fine. But I don't want the (often very long) results to be included for each event at http://mysite/api/events. There are way too many. I'd only like to see results included when I go to http://mysite/api/events/id.

Any tips on how I can get from where I am to where I want to be? It would be even better if each item on http://mysite/api/events included a count of the results, then http://mysite/api/events/id actually had the results.

Hope this made sense.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create 2 serializers `EventSerializer` and `EventDetailSerializer` which will return different serialized representations based on the type of request.

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

class EventDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    results = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) # contain the serialized results
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

Then we will **override the `get_serializer_class()` of `EventViewSet`** which return `EventDetailSerializer` in case of `retrieve` requests and `EventSerializer` otherwise.

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve': # check if a 'retrieve' request
            return EventDetailSerializer 
        return EventSerializer # otherwise return this serializer
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, nice and clean. Thanks!

Comment: @user3449833 Also, to include the count of `results` for each event in your serializer representation for `list` requests,  you can add a `result` [`SerializerMethodField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)in your `EventSerializer`.